# How to set ListView Height dynamically onClick inside a custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, height

This is the situation;
I've a ListView with custom adapter. Each list item includes a button and a hidden TextView(Visibility=GONE). When we click on the button it displays the hidden textview. 
Up to this it works perfectly.

Problem is, when the TextView is shown, the height of the ListView should increase accordingly.
I tried to adjust the height like..

```
list=(ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams l= lst.getLayoutParams();
l.height=l.height+150; //assuming the height of the TextView is 150
list.setLayoutParams(l);
```

But it doesn't work perfectly. I mean, height is increased, but it messes with the previous portion. Ie; Now when i click on the button, it doesn't show the corresponding TextView. Its shows TextView in some other ListItem.

Please help me to find a solution for this;
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Well Asked, Can be better if you can post screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Unlike using View.Gone, set visibility as View.INVISIBLE. After clicking, textview should be  set as View.VISIBLE. Gone means that TextView should not hold layout.
Lets look at [View definations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Could you send listview, xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I think, setting visibility as View.INVISIBLE will cause the view reserve some space. Which may lead to create to some unwanted blank space in the list. I want to create some space whenever the user expands the list.

Comment: In adapter layout for listview, you can solve problem using relative layout and giving absolute height values rather then using wrap_content. Then you can use View.Gone.